Взаимоисключающие фильтрация и сортировка на laravel
Я делаю сайт по поиску обоев на laravel и на нем есть 2 функции: фильтрации и сортировки, и они взаимоисключают друг друга.
Вот мои роуты:
Route::prefix('Wallpapers')->group(function () {

    Route::get("/", [ OutputImageContoller::class, 'showImage']);

    Route::get("/search", [ OutputImageContoller::class, 'search'])->name('output.search');

    Route::get("/sort/{by}", [ OutputImageContoller::class, 'sortBy'])->name('output.sort');

    Route::get("/image/{imageId}", [ ImageController::class, 'showImage'])->name('image.show');

    Route::get("/category/{category}", [ OutputImageContoller::class, 'selectionByCategory'])->name('output.sortByCategory');

    Route::get("/resolution/{resolution}", [ OutputImageContoller::class, 'selectionByResolution'])->name('output.sortByResolution');

});

И вот вызов этих роутов:
        <ul>

            <li><a name="8k" href="{{ route('output.sortByResolution', ['resolution' => '8k'])}}" >7680x4320</a></li>

            <li><a name="4k" href="{{ route('output.sortByResolution', ['resolution' => '4k'])}}" >3840x2160</a></li>

            <li><a name="2k" href="{{ route('output.sortByResolution', ['resolution' => '2k'])}}" >2560x1440</a></li>

            <li><a name="4k" href="{{ route('output.sortByResolution', ['resolution' => 'fullhd'])}}" >1920x1080</a></li>

        </ul>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'all'])}}" >Все категории</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'th'])}}" >Технологии</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'ab'])}}" >Абстракция</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'sp'])}}" >Спорт</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'mv'])}}" >Марвел</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'an'])}}">Аниме</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'au'])}}">Автомобили</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'gm'])}}">Игры</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'mc'])}}">Мотоциклы</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'sc'])}}">Космос</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'mu'])}}">Музыка</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('output.sortByCategory', ['category' => 'am'])}}">Животные</a></li>

        </ul>

Как сделать так чтобы по запросу вроде
Wallpapers.com/category/au/resolution/fullhd/
у меня одновременно включалась и сортировка и фильтрация на странице?

Изменять код методов чтобы они применяли как фильтрацию, ТАК и сортировку. Одно не исключает другого.
